# v-for render html table with multiple tr

Tags: vue.js

I have a table where each "logical" row contains of two "markup rows".

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <template v-for="(note, index) in notes">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{ moment(note.noteTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm') }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ note.locationName }}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    {{ note.noteText }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </template>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there a way generate this kind of table in vue without hurting html syntax (template element is not valid inside tbody)?

Comment: `template` element is just virtual wrapper it will not exist in result html, so your template should work

Comment: Are you asking because of Internet Explorer?

Comment: But when html comes form the server (before vue initialization) is it valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<template>` does not generate a html element and thus will not interfere with html syntax.
There is actually a similar example inside the VueJS docs:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-on-a-lt-template-gt

```
<ul>
  <template v-for="item in items">
    <li>{{ item.msg }}</li>
    <li class="divider" role="presentation"></li>
  </template>
</ul>
```

Here is a jsFiddle to see the example from the docs in action. You can inspect the HTML syntax:

https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/545901/

Comment: Yes, i know that template is 'virtual' element but i'm asking about html validity before vue initialization (javascript not processed html yet).

Comment: Why is this a concern for you? The browser will only see the rendered HTML and then the validity of the syntax can become a concern

Comment: I'm concerned about seo ranks in this kind of scenario. There was a time when html validity was an ingredient of seo rank.

Comment: I am not sure if a crawler will ever get to see the VueJS template code (except you have an error or js is disabled, but that should be handled elsewhere). Other than that i am not sure if the search engine crawlers really care about valid HTML as long as they can parse it - Google for example does not seem to care about valid markup.

Comment: Ok, thanks for additional information. It seems you are quite right https://www.hobo-web.co.uk/official-google-prefers-valid-html-css/ - everything should be ok if google boot will manage to parse html without errors

Comment: well, i have another issue with that code loosely connected with html markup validity in IE11 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51621690/v-for-produces-error-on-ie11. I think its good to be noticed here.